# Rails: whenever + delayed_job to optimize rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake, delayed-job, whenever

I use **whenever** to call rake tasks throughout the day, but each task launches a new Rails environment. How can I run tasks throughout the day without relaunching Rails for each job?

Here's what I came up with, would love to get some feedback on this...?

1. Refactor each rake task to instead be a method within the appropriate Model.
2. Use the **delayed_job** gem to assign low priority and ensure these methods run asynchronously.
3. Instruct **whenever** to call each Model.method instead of calling the rake task

Does this solution make sense? Will it help avoid launching a new Rails environment for each job? .. or is there a better way to do this?

--

Running Rails 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of good solutions to this problem, the one I eventually ended up integrating is as such:

1. Moved my rake code to the appropriate models
2. Added controller/routing code for calling models methods from the browser
3. Configured cronjobs using the `whenever` gem to run `command 'curl mywebsite.com/model#method'`

I tried giving delayed_job a go but didn't like the idea of running another Rails instance. My methods are not too server intensive, and the above solution allows me to utilize the already-running Rails environment.

Comment: I also have used this method and I like it.  A curl or wget request to kick everything off.  It fits well with the REST model and integrates cleanly with cron or something else.  Having a ruby script on the side is kind of messy and doesn't help with DRY.

Comment: Just wondering, if there is a way to authenticate so outsider won't perform DDOS on the server?

Comment: @lulalala if you only have one server, you can check if the IP the server is residing on is the same as the IP making the request. In my case, I configured nginx to only allow a handful of IPs to access the cron URLs.

Comment: Isn't this pretty insecure?

Comment: I don't see why it would be. I'm only accepting connections originating locally because there's no reason to allow outside requests. I handle this via nginx but you could just as easily do this via Rails itself.

Answer (score 4):

You could certainly look into enqueuing delayed_jobs via cron, then having one long running delayed_job worker.

Then you could use `whenever` to help you create the delayed_job enqueuing methods. It's probably easiest to have `whenever`'s cron output call a small wrapper script which loads active_record and delayed_job directly rather than your whole rails stack. http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/257-How-to-use-ActiveRecord-without-Rails

You might also like to look into clockwork.rb, which is a long-running process that would do the same thing you're using cron for (enqueuing delayed_jobs): http://rubydoc.info/gems/clockwork/0.2.3/frames

You could also just try using a requeuing strategy in your delayed_jobs: https://gist.github.com/704047

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line from schedule.rb

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/environment")
```

Instead load only required ruby files like models in your case.